# An equivalent of xpd=TRUE for ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I am playing with ggvis and came up with the following code:

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% ggvis(~disp, ~wt) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  scale_numeric("x", domain = input_slider(50, 500, c(100, 400)), nice = FALSE) %>%
  scale_numeric("y", domain = input_slider(0, 6, c(1, 5)), nice = FALSE)
```

This enables me to dynamically resize the plot. The problem is that when resizing some of the data points are plotted outside the range. Is there an option like `xpd=TRUE` for base R graph to clip the plotting region, so that the data points not in the range of axes are not plotted?

Comment: I do not see that option implemented yet, though `clamp = TRUE` for scales at least prevents points from falling outside. FWIW, I think that it is possible to achieve the effect you want by using shiny and dynamically subsetting only the data that is bounded by sliders.

Comment: Yes, `clamp=TRUE` helps. Although it would be nice to control the visual properties of the clamped points.